# JPA(hibernate) atualizar entidades automaticamente

Tags: hibernate, primefaces, jpa, jpa-2.0

Estou com a seguinte dúvida: percebi que ao utilizar a JPA (Hibernate) + Spring em uma aplicação JSF (PrimeFaces) minhas entidades não são atualizadas de imediato ao realizar um cadastro, por exemplo, possuo uma tela de cadastro de Usuários onde ao realizar o mesmo tudo ocorre normalmente, as informações são persistidas no banco de dados, mas ao tentar utilizar por exemplo um componente auto-complete em outra página o registro da entidade recém adicionada não aparece, a menos que eu reinicie o servidor, após a reinicialização tudo funciona normalmente.

Criei o tópico na sessão de JPA pois pesquisando pela internet, creio que seja algo relacionado a configuração de Cache do hibernate porém ainda não consegui encontrar a solução, caso alguém ja tenha passo por isso ou tenha alguma luz sobre o assunto me avise por favor.

Obrigado, até mais

Comment: mais detalhes, por favor...
não consegui identificar se o problema é realmente de persistência.
poste o código e seus arquivos de configuração, o persistence.xml por exemplo. só o necessário para uma boa análise.